# Changing the baseline record for flyway

Tags: java, database, flyway

I have a database which I run migrations using flyway on. It has a `schema_version` table that has a record:

```
'1', '1', '1', '<< Flyway Baseline >>', 'BASELINE', '<< Flyway Baseline >>', NULL, 'root', '2016-06-28 16:59:05', '0', '1'
```

Now I need to introduce some earlier migrations than 1, ex: 0.0.1. These migrations are ignored because the baseline is 1. Can I change the baseline record in the `schema_version` table?

Note: I use java api.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Seems like a confusing request though - you want to add in migrations that should be run but are also pre-baseline (which means they shouldn't be run).

What you will have to do is delete your `schema_version` and run `baseline` + `migrate` again with your new `baselineVersion`.

You could manually tweak the baseline entry in `schema_version` but I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: The baseline version in the  schema_version version table is old. That's why I asked if I can change that record in the schema_version table.
Is there no way to do this from the java api, i.e. without manually updating the record or deleting the table?
Thank you.

Comment: Correct. No way to "re-baseline" an existing `schema_version` table (through any Flyway API). You have to undergo some manual remedial procedure yourself, like modifying or dropping the `schema_version` table.

Answer (score 2):

I can give some use cases on when changing the baseline is needed:

- a schema is created from an older dump (not containing flyway information) and we do not know exactly what should be the baseline.
- somebody has applied (SQL) migration steps without using flyway, so we have to make flyway aware of that.